# Change co-ordinate on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD83DW4cuDAMp0Zf2GkEXGFqnBAewN5qko"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          function init(locations){
            var element = document.getElementById("map");

            var mapTypeIds = [];
            for(var type in google.maps.MapTypeId) {
                mapTypeIds.push(google.maps.MapTypeId[type]);
            }
            mapTypeIds.push("OSM");

            var map = new google.maps.Map(element, {
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(locations[0].lat), parseInt(locations[0].lng)),
                                zoom: 6,
              mapTypeId: "OSM",
              mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: mapTypeIds
              }
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
                map: map,
                draggable:true,
                // title: locations[i].lat
                // icon: image
              });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                  infoWindow.setContent(locations[i].infowindow);
                  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, i));

              var mapTypeIds = [];
              for(var type in google.maps.MapTypeId) {
                  mapTypeIds.push(google.maps.MapTypeId[type]);
              }
              mapTypeIds.push("OSM");

              map.mapTypes.set("OSM", new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                    return "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
                },
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                name: "OpenStreetMap",
                maxZoom: 18
              }));
            }
          }
          // long 77.4028193  lat 23.2243851
          var locations = [{"lat":"21.2243851","lng":"77.4028193","infowindow":" information1 "},{"lat":"17.433282","lng":"78.426762","infowindow":" information2 "}];
          var locations1 = [{"lat":"24.2243851","lng":"77.4028193","infowindow":" information1 "},{"lat":"17.434282","lng":"78.426762","infowindow":" information2 "}];


          window.onload = init(locations);
          window.setInterval( function(){console.log("first fn");change(locations1);}, 3500);
          window.setInterval( function(){console.log("second fn");change(locations);}, 1500);
          function change(locations){
            console.log(locations);

            var mapTypeIds = [];
            for(var type in google.maps.MapTypeId) {
                mapTypeIds.push(google.maps.MapTypeId[type]);
            }
            mapTypeIds.push("OSM");
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 6,
              center: {lat: parseInt(locations[0].lat), lng: parseInt(locations[0].lng)},
              mapTypeId: "OSM",
              mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: mapTypeIds
              }
            });

            // var map = google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng),
              });
              marker.setMap(map);
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                  infoWindow.setContent(locations[i].infowindow);
                  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
              })(marker, i));
              var mapTypeIds = [];
              for(var type in google.maps.MapTypeId) {
                mapTypeIds.push(google.maps.MapTypeId[type]);
              }
              mapTypeIds.push("OSM");

              map.mapTypes.set("OSM", new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                    return "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
                },
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                name: "OpenStreetMap",
                maxZoom: 18
              }));
            }
          }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

without reloading/refreshing googlemap markers to be replaced. Tried all the ways provided by google-map api and other blogs. nothing helping me, atlast posting here hoping someone helps me with this part.

I have copied complete code here so that it helps to get on to the issue on which I am trying to solve.

Comment: you should put an ajax tag in your question

Comment: tried with ajax but that din't help me

Answer (score 1):

Here I do.Is this right. I modified some of your code to make sure if this what you wish. I think you just miss some detail. If this is what you want, please let me know. PS :A lot of forloop in the function change-->not a good example.XD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var map;
 var markersArray=[];//put all markers into this
      function init(locations){
        var element = document.getElementById("map");

        var mapTypeIds = [];
        for(var type in google.maps.MapTypeId) {
            mapTypeIds.push(google.maps.MapTypeId[type]);
        }
        mapTypeIds.push("OSM");

        map = new google.maps.Map(element, {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(locations[0].lat), parseInt(locations[0].lng)),
                            zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: "OSM",
          mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: mapTypeIds
          }
        });

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {            
          var mapTypeIds = [];
          for(var type in google.maps.MapTypeId) {
              mapTypeIds.push(google.maps.MapTypeId[type]);
          }
          mapTypeIds.push("OSM");

          map.mapTypes.set("OSM", new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                return "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            name: "OpenStreetMap",
            maxZoom: 18
          }));
        }
      }

      var locations = [{"lat":"21.2243851","lng":"77.4028193","infowindow":" information1 "},{"lat":"20.433282","lng":"78.426762","infowindow":" information2 "}];
      var locations1 = [{"lat":"24.2243851","lng":"77.4028193","infowindow":" information1 "},{"lat":"22.434282","lng":"78.426762","infowindow":" information2 "}];

      var counter=0;
      window.onload = init(locations);
      window.setInterval( function(){
        if(counter%2==0)
        {
         change(locations1);
        }
         else
        {
         change(locations);
        }
        counter++;
    }, 2000);


      function change(locations){

          for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
          {  
            if(markersArray[i]!=null)
            {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
                if (i == locations.length - 1) {
                    markersArray = [];
                }
            }   
          }

          for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
          {    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lng)  }); 
            markersArray.push(marker);    

          }
          for (i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++)
         {
               markersArray[i].setMap(map);
         }

      }

    </script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. If you could run my the code you will observe that co-ordinates on the map getting changed and **map is reloading which I don't want** . line number 80 which is
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')
which is loading map. ** I feel something I need to change or need to modify at line number 80**

Comment: var map = new google.maps.Map(docum var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') ent.getElementById('map')  -->For What? You recreate the map, so it will clear all up and reload. What are results  you want? If you just want to change the coordinate, you don't have to do so.

Comment: To get googlemap Dom element I tried that way which I feel is wrong way. Looking for that answer

Comment: So what you want to do is change the coordinate of marker and then refresh the marker to your new position,right?

Comment: Now i have cam to point where map is not refreshing/reloading any more. I am into a problem where markers need to removed and has to be replaced with the new once.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem to what you are experiencing.  The way we solved it was by recalculating the bounds and recentering the map each time a new location is added.  So basically we have a createMarker function that has this bit of code at the end:

```
const map_center = bounds.getCenter();
      resultsMap.setCenter(map_center);
      resultsMap.panToBounds(bounds);
      resultsMap.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Where `bounds` here is your map boundaries, which can be found with the  `google.maps.LatLngBounds()` method.

EDIT: I see you want to do it without refreshing the map, I don't think resetting the bounds refreshes the map but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Fitting map is not the issue here. If you run the code you will understand that I am trying to change co-ordinate with which whole map is re-loading. which I don't want..
I just want map to replace latitude and longitude co-ordinate without reload/refreshing googlemap

Comment: If you could run my the code you will observe that co-ordinates on the map getting changed and map is reloading which I don't want . line number 80 which is var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map') which is re-loading map. ** I feel something I need to change or need to modify at line number 80**